# LinkedList of Python Classes

Tags: python, linked-list, metaclass

**Very simple Overview of Problem Statement:**
Given *Object Name, object attribute information*

```
'A',{"a":1}
'B',{"b":2}
'C',{"c":3}
```

Trying to create a single object which called (obj) which has A object as attribute, B is an attribute of A and so on and so forth.....

Can one suggest how I can create dynamically such objects in Python? I was thinking to use MetaClass.

```
A = type("A",(object,),{"a":1})
B = type("B",(A,),{"b":2})
C = type("C",(B,),{"c":3})
```

But it is just passing the attribute not the whole class. My object structure needs to be such that:
Result:

```
   >>>print(obj.A.a)
   >>>print(obj.A.B.b)
   >>>print(obj.A.B.C.c)
```

will give:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Shouldn't `A` go into the dictionary of attributes of `B` and so on?

Comment: how will you pass object A into object B's dictionary or namespace? That is the q

Comment: Do you want `obj.A.B` to be a class or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no point to using a `type` for this, just use a `SimpleNamepace`:

```
In [1]: from types import SimpleNamespace

In [2]: data =  {
   ...: 'A':{"a":1},
   ...: 'B':{"b":2},
   ...: 'C':{"c":3},
   ...: }

In [3]: obj = SimpleNamespace()
   ...: curr = obj
   ...: for k, attrs in data.items():
   ...:     new = SimpleNamespace(**attrs)
   ...:     setattr(curr, k,  new)
   ...:     curr = new
   ...:

In [4]: obj
Out[4]: namespace(A=namespace(a=1, B=namespace(b=2, C=namespace(c=3))))

In [5]: obj.A.a, obj.A.B.b, obj.A.B.C.c
Out[5]: (1, 2, 3)
```

A simple namespace is basically:

```
class Namespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        vars(self).update(kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exctly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental problem here.  You want class A to contain a B, but you want B to derive from A. You cannot do both things in one statement.  It's possible you achieve your structure, but it seems kind of silly:

```
base = type('base',(object,),{})

A = type("A",(base,),{"a":1})
base.A=A

B = type("B",(A,),{"b":2})
A.B=B

C = type("C",(B,),{"c":3})
B.C=C

obj = base()
print(obj.A.a)
print(obj.A.B.b)
print(obj.A.B.C.c)
```

Comment: I actually don't think inheritance is implied.

Comment: His example shows inheritance, but the problem is described very vaguely, with no mention of use cases.